# Java Tower Of Hanoi convert number to String

Tags: java

Java Tower Of Hanoi convert numbers looping result to String result

How to make print statement into letters instead of numbers, the print is like this

1  |     |
2  |     |
3  |     |

i want to change to letters like this

a  |     |
b  |     |
c  |     |

I try using if-else for every time I print d1, d2, and d3, but d1,d2, and d3, don't have have of 1,2, and 3 so I cant use conditional statement to change di value into a string

can you help me with this problem

```
     import java.util.*;
     
     /* Class TowerOfHanoiUsingStacks */
     public class HelloWorld
     {
         public static int N;
         /* Creating Stack array  */
         public static Stack<Integer>[] tower = new Stack[4]; 
     
         public static void main(String[] args)
         {
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             tower[1] = new Stack<Integer>();
             tower[2] = new Stack<Integer>();
             tower[3] = new Stack<Integer>();
             /* Accepting number of disks */         
             System.out.println("Enter number of disks");
             int num = scan.nextInt();
             N = num;
             toh(num);
         }
         /* Function to push disks into stack */
         public static void toh(int n)
         {
             for (int d = n; d > 0; d--)
                 tower[1].push(d);
             display();
             move(n, 1, 2, 3);         
         }
         /* Recursive Function to move disks */
         public static void move(int n, int a, int b, int c)
         {
             if (n > 0)
             {
                 move(n-1, a, c, b);     
                 int d = tower[a].pop();                                             
                 tower[c].push(d);
                 display();                   
                 move(n-1, b, a, c);     
             }         
         }
         /*  Function to display */
         public static void display()
         {
             System.out.println("  A  |  B  |  C");
             System.out.println("---------------");
             for(int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
             {
                 String d1 = " ", d2 = " ", d3 = " ";
                 try
                 {
                     d1 = String.valueOf(tower[1].get(i));
                 }
                 catch (Exception e){
                 }    
                 try
                 {
                     d2 = String.valueOf(tower[2].get(i));
                 }
                 catch(Exception e){
                 }
                 try
                 {
                     d3 = String.valueOf(tower[3].get(i));
                 }
                 catch (Exception e){
                 }
                 System.out.println("  "+d1+"  |  "+d2+"  |  "+d3);
             }
             System.out.println("\n");         
         }
     }
```

Comment: Never catch exception without handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print letters instead of numbers, cast your value to char

`String.valueOf((char)(tower[1].get(i) + 97))`

You might want to use `96` instead, since I believe you are using `1` as the first index.

Comment: Your welcome. Please also take time to go through the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for better framing your questions on SO for your next time around. Also, mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your issue, so that the question no longer appears unanswered.